# Using Getters and Setters to modify values w/o Subclassing in Swift

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a class, and when I set its property, I want it to append that property with a file type like `.fileType`:

```
class File {
    var fileName: String {
    get {
        return self.fileName
    }
    set {
        self.fileName = fileName + ".fileType"
    }
    }
}
```

Which I try to use like this:

```
let newFile = File()
newFile.fileName = "My File"
```

Unfortunately, the variable never sets:

[image: Checkpoints]

I have two possible workarounds.

#### Option 1: Observe Value After Set

```
class File {
    var fileName: String = "" {
    didSet {
        self.fileName += ".fileType"
    }
    }
}

let file = File()
file.fileName = "SomeName" // SomeName.fileType
```

But with this, I must wait until the value is already set before I can modify it.  For this particular example, it doesn't make too much difference; however, I'd like to be able to avoid this.

#### Option 2: Subclass

This solution is based on the example [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-XID_265)  Search for 'speedLimitedCar'

```
class File {
    var fileName = ""
}

class SubFile: File {

    override var fileName: String {
    get {
        return super.fileName
    }
    set {
        super.fileName = newValue + ".fileType"
    }
    }
}

let subfile = SubFile()
subfile.fileName = "Hello" // Hello.fileType
```

#### Question

I could also just create a secondary property to store the value and access that in the fileName's getter/setter, but is there a way to avoid all that and modify a property directly within its getter / setter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use `set` and `get` then the property must be computed. There is no actual storage for it.

This code defines a `var` to hold the data and a computed `var` to handle the access. This is similar to what you had in Objective-C (except that in Objective-C you could "hide" the actual variable by making it private or, more recently, having it synthesized an never mentioned in the header).

```
class File {
    // this stores the actual data, do not access it directly, consider it private
    var theFileName: String = ""

    // this is the real interface
    var fileName: String {
        get {
            return self.theFileName
        }
        set(name) {
            self.theFileName = name + ".fileType"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also write the `set` like this:

```
set {
    self.theFileName = newValue + ".fileType"
}
```

where `newValue` is the default name if you omit the argument declaration for `set`.

But what you probably want to do is what you already did (and rejected for unknown reasons):

```
var fileName: String = "" {
    didSet {
        self.fileName += ".fileType"
    }
}
```

This is the correct way.

Note that "I must wait until the value is already set before I can modify it." is not true. It *looks* like that, but the compiler can very well optimize the code (and probably will).

Comment: Why is setting in the `didSet` not recursive?

Comment: @moby because that's how the didSet observer is implemented behind the scenes. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html (in particular the note right before the "Global and Local Variables" section).