# Property observers willSet and didSet; Property getters and setters

Tags: swift, properties, didset, property-observer

What is the difference between `willSet` - `didSet`, and `get` - `set`, when working with this inside a property?

From my point of view, both of them can set a value for a property. When, and why, should I use `willSet` - `didSet`, and when `get` - `set`?

I know that for `willSet` and `didSet`, the structure looks like this:

```
var variable1 : Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        println (variable1)
    }
    willSet(newValue) {
    ..
    }
}

var variable2: Int {
    get {
        return variable2
    }
    set (newValue){
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of willSet and didSet in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006234/what-is-the-purpose-of-willset-and-didset-in-swift)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> When and why should I use willSet/didSet

- `willSet` is called just **before** the value is stored.
- `didSet` is called immediately **after** the new value is stored.

Consider your example with outputs:

---

```
var variable1 : Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            print("didSet called")
        }
        willSet(newValue){
            print("willSet called")
        }
    }

    print("we are going to add 3")

     variable1 = 3

    print("we added 3")
```

Output:

```
we are going to add 3
willSet called
didSet called
we added 3
```

it works like pre/post -condition

On the other hand, you can use `get` if you want to add, for example, a read-only property:

```
var value : Int {
 get {
    return 34
 }
}

print(value)

value = 2 // error: cannot assign to a get-only property 'value'
```

Answer (score 26):

@Maxim's answer is for the 1st part of your question.

As for when to use `get` and `set`: when you want a computed property. This:

```
var x: Int
```

creates a *stored property*, which is automatically backed up by a variable (not directly accessible though). Setting a value to that property is translated in setting the value in the property, and similarly for getting.

Instead:

```
var y = {
    get { return x + 5 }
    set { x = newValue - 5}
}
```

will create a computed property, which is not backed up by a variable - instead you have to provide the implementation of the getter and/or setter, usually reading and writing values from another property and more generally as a result of a computation (hence the *computed property* name)

Suggested reading: [Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_368)

**Note**: your code:

```
var variable2: Int {
    get{
        return variable2
    }
    set (newValue){
    }
}
```

is **wrong** because in the `get` you are trying to return itself, which means calling `get` recursively. And in fact the compiler will warn you with a message like `Attempting to access 'variable2' within its own getter`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var variable1 : Int = 0 { //It's a store property
    didSet {
        print (variable1)
    }
    willSet(newValue) {
    ..
    }
}

var variable2: Int { //It's a Computed Proprties
    get {
        return variable2
    }
    set (newValue){
    }
}
```

For detail info of [Store property and computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) 
So when you are trying to assign the value into variable at that assigning time come the concept of 'didSet' & 'willSet'. As @Maxim says

- **willSet** is called just **before** the value is stored.
- **didSet** is called immediately **after** the new value is stored.

Example of 'willSet' & 'didSet' :

```
class Number {
   var variable1 : Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            print("didSet called")
        }
        willSet(newValue){
            print("willSet called")
        }

    }
}
print("we are going to add 3")
Number().variable1 = 3
print("we added 3")
```

> //o/p:
>  we are going to add 3
>  willSet called
>  didSet
>   called
>  we added 3

And generally when two property are dependent at that time 'get' & 'set' used. (It's also used in [protocol](https://vishal-singh-panwar.github.io/SwiftProtocols/) this is different concept.)

Example of 'get' & 'set':

```
class EquilateralTriangle{
    var sideLength: Double = 0.0
    init(sideLength: Double){
        self.sideLength = sideLength
    }
    var perimeter: Double {
        get {
            return 3.0 * sideLength
        }
        set {
            sideLength = newValue / 3.0
        }
    }

}

var triangle = EquilateralTriangle(sideLength: 3.0)
print(triangle.perimeter) //o/p: 9.0
triangle.perimeter = 12.0
print(triangle.sideLength) //o/p: 4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

**get set**:

> `get` `set` are **Computed Properties** Which **do not actually store a
>   value**. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter to
>   retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly

Additionally you can define Read-Only Computed Properties.
A read-only computed property always returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but cannot be set to a different value

*Example get only property-*

```
 var number: Double {
        return .pi*2
    }
```

**willSet didSet**:

> `willSet` `didSet` are **Property Observers**
>
> Property observers observe and respond to changes in a property’s
>   value. Property observers are called every time a property’s value is
>   set, even if the new value is the same as the property’s current
>   value.

- willSet is called just before the value is stored.
- didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored.

*Example -*

```
var score: Int = 0 {
    willSet(newScore) {
        print("willSet  score to \(newScore)")
    }
    didSet {
        print("didSet score to \(oldValue) new score is: \(score)")
    }
}
score = 10
//Output 
//willSet  score to 10
//didSet score to 0 new score is: 10
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Answer (score 1):

### get set

You can use a regular `get-and-set` syntax in case you want to implement gettable and settable property. However, you may use just `get` syntax in case you implement `read-only` property. With `setter` you are given a `newValue` property.

```
class GetterSetter {
    var theValue: Bool = false
    var property: Bool {
        get { return theValue }
        set {
            print("Value changed from \(theValue) to \(newValue)")
            theValue = newValue
        }
    }
}

let getterSetter = GetterSetter()
getterSetter.property = true
getterSetter.property

// PRINTS:
// Value changed from 'false' to 'true'
```

### didSet

`didSet` **property observer** is used in case we need to execute a code when a property has just been set. Implementing `didSet` you are given `oldValue` to represent the previous value.

```
class DidSetter {
    var property: Float16 = -1.0 {
        didSet {
            print("Value changed from \(oldValue) to \(property)")
        }
    }
}

let didSetter = DidSetter()
didSetter.property = 5.0
didSetter.property

// PRINTS:
// Value changed from -1.0 to 5.0
```

### willSet

`willSet` **property observer** is used in case we need to execute a code before a property has been set. Implementing `willSet` you are given `newValue` to represent the new property value that it's going to be.

```
class WillSetter {
    var property: String = "NO" {
        willSet {
            print("Value changed from \(property) to \(newValue)")
        }
    }
}

let willSetter = WillSetter()
willSetter.property = "YES"
willSetter.property

// PRINTS:
// Value changed from NO to YES
```