# What is the use of "didSet","get","set" in Swift protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols, didset

Where should I use set or get method during calling Protocol or Delegate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift willSet didSet and get set methods in a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398753/swift-willset-didset-and-get-set-methods-in-a-property)

Comment: `didSet` is not used in protocol declarations. Everything else is described in [Swift Language Guide:Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set and Get are for setting and getting any value to and from properties and not for protocols.Delegation is used to receive a call back from another controller.