# Use didSet while initialising a variable

Tags: ios, swift, properties, didset

I have one array `results` which I am using to set another array `filteredResult` which contains some filtered value of the main `results` array.

```
var filteredResult: [Result] {
    var result = self.results.filter({ $0.exclusive == true })

    result = result.filter({ $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("Test Name") })

    return result
}
```

Now I will have to perform some task after this `filteredResult` array is set. So where to perform that task? I have tried `didSet` after `get` but I'm getting error

> DidSet variable may not also have a get specifier

```
var filteredResult: [Result] {
    get {
        var result = self.results.filter({ $0.exclusive == true })

        result = result.filter({ $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("Test Name") })

        return result
    }
    didSet {

    }
}
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398753/swift-willset-didset-and-get-set-methods-in-a-property) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006234/what-is-the-purpose-of-willset-and-didset-in-swift) links. But not able to get the solution.

So kindly help me to understand how to perform some task after `filteredResult` is set with some filter value.

Comment: You cannot apply a property observer to a computed property.

Comment: so where to perform some task after `filteredResult` is set?

Comment: At the moment you don't have a setter. `filteredResult` is read-only. Implement the setter (`set { ... }`) and perform the task there.

Comment: Add the `didSet` to `results`, since I'm guessing that that's a stored property.

Comment: Yes I have `didSet` in `results` and used to perform that task from there. But now I'll need to use `filteredResult` to perform that task.

Comment: PS: Strictly spoken *Use didSet while initialising a variable* doesn't work anyway because the property observer is not called while initialising a variable.