# Can not see table view items without touching down the screen

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, nsmutableurlrequest

There is some problem in my tableView class I have got the data from my server and can show in table View but problem is that when I have completely got the data from server it never shown in table view until I touched down my screen.. when I touched my screen down I can see my data but I want to see my data when I have got the data.. here is my class
..

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MovementRep : UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


var unitID : Int = 0;
var count : Int = 0;

var dateTime = [String]()
var speed = [Double]()
var event = [String]()
var location = [String]()

var len : Int = 0;

var deviation = [String]()


@IBOutlet weak var ActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Movement Report Called");
    print("unit ID = \(unitID)")

    var id : String = String(self.unitID);
    print("string id = \(id)")


    //Send Server Request

    let myURL = NSURL(string: "<URL>");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";





    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, responce, error in


        self.ActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

        if error != nil{
            print("Error = \(error)")

        }

      //  print("Responce = \(responce)")



        //    let responceString = NSString(data:data,encodeing:NSTUF8StringEncoding);
        //   print("Responce Data = \(responceString)");


        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

             //   print("JSONResult = \(jsonResult)")

                let size = jsonResult["size"] as? Int
                print("result: \(size)");

                self.len = size!;

                if let Users = jsonResult["movementReport"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {


                    //when you got irrespective response of numberOfRowsInSe...

                    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498531/numberofrowsinsection-is-called-before-alamofire-connection/31498570#31498570

                    self.tableView.reloadData()


                    for name in Users {



                        //if you got null from Json ...
                        if let msg = name["message"] as? NSNull{
                            //print("got \(d)")
                            self.location.append("null")
                        }

                        //simple chk
                        if let message = name["message"] as? String
                        {

                            self.location.append(message)


                        }

                        //if you got null from Json ...
                        if let dt = name["dateTime"] as? NSNull{
                            //print("got \(d)")
                            self.location.append("null")
                        }

                        //simple chk
                        if let date = name["dateTime"] as? String
                        {

                            self.dateTime.append(date)


                        }

                        //if you got null from Json ...
                        if let sp = name["speed"] as? NSNull{
                            //print("got \(d)")
                            self.speed.append(0.0)
                        }

                        //simple chk
                        if let speed = name["speed"] as? Double
                        {

                            self.speed.append(speed)


                        }




                        //if you got null from Json ...
                        if let ev = name["reportText"] as? NSNull{
                            //print("got \(d)")
                            self.event.append("null")
                        }

                        //simple chk
                        if let event = name["reportText"] as? String

                        {

                            self.event.append(event)


                        }

                        //if you got null from Json ...
                        if let dev = name["route"] as? NSNull{
                            //print("got \(d)")
                            self.deviation.append("--")
                        }

                        //simple chk
                        if let devtion = name["route"] as? String

                        {

                            self.deviation.append(devtion)

                        }

                    }

                }


            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }




    task.resume();

    self.tableView.reloadData();


}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print("ViewWillAppearCaled")

   self.tableView.reloadData();
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print("ViewDidAppearCaled")
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("table view row")
    return len
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("table view cell")

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if (len > 0){

    cell.date.text = dateTime[indexPath.row];
    cell.speed.text = "\(speed[indexPath.row])"
    cell.position.text = event[indexPath.row]
    cell.location.text = location[indexPath.row]
    cell.deviation.text = deviation[indexPath.row]
         cell.index.text = "\(indexPath.row+1)";
         self.ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()

         return cell

    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(6, 6, self.view.frame.size.width, 200.0))

    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    //whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1

        cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
        cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteRoundedView)
    }


}
```

Comment: have you try with reloading table only once at the end of setting all api response data?

Comment: and how can I do this? I am not try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with replacing this code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Movement Report Called");
    print("unit ID = \(unitID)")

    var id : String = String(self.unitID);
    print("string id = \(id)")

    self.ActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {

        let myURL = NSURL(string: "<URL>");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, responce, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("Error = \(error)")

        }

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                let size = jsonResult["size"] as? Int
                print("result: \(size)");

                self.len = size!;

                if let Users = jsonResult["movementReport"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    for name in Users {

                        //if you got null from Json ...
                        if let msg = name["message"] as? NSNull{
                            //print("got \(d)")
                            self.location.append("null")
                        }

                        //simple chk
                        if let message = name["message"] as? String
                        {

                            self.location.append(message)


                        }

                        //if you got null from Json ...
                        if let dt = name["dateTime"] as? NSNull{
                            //print("got \(d)")
                            self.location.append("null")
                        }

                        //simple chk
                        if let date = name["dateTime"] as? String
                        {

                            self.dateTime.append(date)


                        }

                        //if you got null from Json ...
                        if let sp = name["speed"] as? NSNull{
                            //print("got \(d)")
                            self.speed.append(0.0)
                        }

                        //simple chk
                        if let speed = name["speed"] as? Double
                        {

                            self.speed.append(speed)


                        }




                        //if you got null from Json ...
                        if let ev = name["reportText"] as? NSNull{
                            //print("got \(d)")
                            self.event.append("null")
                        }

                        //simple chk
                        if let event = name["reportText"] as? String

                        {

                            self.event.append(event)


                        }

                        //if you got null from Json ...
                        if let dev = name["route"] as? NSNull{
                            //print("got \(d)")
                            self.deviation.append("--")
                        }

                        //simple chk
                        if let devtion = name["route"] as? String

                        {

                            self.deviation.append(devtion)

                        }

                    }
                    self.ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                        self.tableView?.reloadData()
                    }

                }


            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }




    task.resume();
    })

}
```

Comment: nothing change.. again.. result show in the touch event.

Comment: i have edited the answer. Give one try to updated code as i have put api call in background thread and reloading of table view data in main queue.