# changing the value of a variable from another class in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a custom UISegment Control

```
@IBDesignable class CardsSegmentedControl: UIControl {

private var labels = [UILabel]()
var thumbView = UIView()


var items: [String] = ["Saved Cards", "Add Card"] {
    didSet {
        setupLabels()
    }
}

var selectedIndex : Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        displayNewSelectedIndex()
    }
}
....
}
```

Now I wish to change the value of the variable `selectedIndex` in the viewController where I am adding this custom segment control in.

I guess it is a problem of how to access/change variables from another class.

I tried to create a `class func` which would set the value of the `selectedIndex` but I cannot get it to access the `selectedIndex` variable either.

Still pretty new to Swift so please bear with me.

Comment: do you have init func?

Comment: no I dont.. Should I set the value of `selectedIndex` using the init function and then use it to change the value elsewhere as well?

Comment: selectedIndex is instance variable, so won't be accessed from class functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Inside your ViewController class, create a new instance of your custom class
var cardSegmentedControl = CardSegmentedControl()

// here, change its property value
cardSegmentedControl.selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: Take a look at this Stackoverflow thread for understanding willSet and didSet actions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006234/what-is-the-purpose-of-willset-and-didset-in-swift