# Swift does the "get" method will change the value of variable?

Tags: swift, lifecycle

I just want to do something when the variable update value, and do not change the value.  But the "get" is required if I implement "set", so I try to return the value self. It looks has already in "hell cycle":

```
var imageInfo:ImageInfo! {

    get {
        return self.imageInfo
    }
    set(info) {
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: info.fileName)
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `didSet` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006234/what-is-the-purpose-of-willset-and-didset-in-swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something when update the value, you should implement `didSet` method.

```
var imageInfo:ImageInfo! {

        didSet{
         // do your stuff here
         self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageInfo.fileName)
        }

}
```

Comment: Man, thanks for help.