# Why IBInspectable not set vaue for optional variable from storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, ibinspectable

I am making a demo for learning how @IBInspectable works.

First, I made two variables in UIViewController subclass:

```
  @IBInspectable var intTest:Int = 10
  @IBInspectable var flag:Bool = false
```

So that it appears in the storyboard. After that, I change the value of those variables in the storyboard:

[image]

Then, I try to print those variables in "viewDidLoad()" method like this:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       print("intTest value: \(String(describing: intTest))")
       print("flag value: \(String(describing: flag)))")
  }
```

The output is:

> intTest value: 90
>
> flag value: true

It works fine, except when I change the variables declaration like,

```
  @IBInspectable var intTest:Int? = 10
  @IBInspectable var flag:Bool? = false
```

After that, I changed the value same as above in the storyboard, but the values are not changed.

Output is:

> intTest value: Optional(10)
>
> flag value: Optional(false)

So my question is, why is the value not updated when i declare the variable as optional?

The another thing is, when I take the variable as a string the value is updated. Can anyone help me understand this functionality?

Answer (score 4):

Set Optional value `IBInspectable` var

```
@IBInspectable var placeHolderImage:UIImage? {
     didSet {
         leftViewSetting()
     }
 }
```

Set default value `IBInspectable` var

```
@IBInspectable var placeHolderImage:UIImage = UIImage() {
    didSet {
        leftViewSetting()
    }
}
```

Using this approach and every time you change the value in Interface Builder`, your view will be updated.

```
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
       return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
       layer.cornerRadius = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that when we declare a variable as optional then the value is not updated but my question is why?

Comment: `@IBInspectable var placeHolderImage:UIImage?` i change IBInspectable var to option its working well. Update your question with your designable class.

Comment: Yes, I found that image is updating same as String.But, my question is why Int and Bool value are not updating?

Answer (score -1):

You can declare it as an optional and it works well .
Just tweak your code as below:

```
 @IBInspectable var intTest: Int? {
        didSet {
            self.intTestTweak = intTest
        }
  }
```

`willSet` and `didSet` are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006234/what-is-the-purpose-of-willset-and-didset-in-swift).