# Variable - didSet and willSet

Tags: swift, variables, didset

I understand how to use `didSet` and `willSet` for variables but not really why. When should I use these methods and why?

Usually when you update a value you have some kind of button for example where you update a `textField` and then set a variables value to the `textFields` for example. If I want to pass something to another `viewController` or I do it in the button action.

So my question is:
When and why should I use `didSet` and `willSet` for my variables?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to observe the value change of a variable. And that's when `didSet` and `willSet` are useful.

`didSet` is called after the value changes, and you can use it to notify some Manager about it or do whatever you need.

`willSet` is sometimes used to modify the value before it is given to the variable. For example, you receive a `String` which is a timestamp from the server, and you want to transform it into a readable date text.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to observe value change for variable you need to user didset/willset of variable.

willSet -- is called just before the value is stored.
didSet -- is called immediately after the new value is stored.

[refer below link for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006234/what-is-the-purpose-of-willset-and-didset-in-swift)