# How do I change the gradient of a collectionviewcell or button on click?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, cell, gradient

I'm using a gradient on my UIViews like this:

```
//the cells gradient colors
    cellgradient.frame = cell.imageView.bounds
    cellgradient.cornerRadius = cellgradient.frame.height / 2
    cellgradient.colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#ef473a")!, UIColor(hexString: "#cb2d3e")!].map { $0.cgColor }
    cellgradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    cellgradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    cellgradient.colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#ef473a")!, UIColor(hexString: "#cb2d3e")!]
    cell.imageView.layer.insertSublayer(cellgradient, at: 0)
```

Now when I select the cell or deselect the cell I want to change the current gradient. How do I do this?

**EDIT**

Based on the answer I did the following:

```
class CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
{

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
public var checked = false
public var animated = false
public var cellgradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

override var bounds : CGRect {
    didSet {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isSelected {
            cellgradient.colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#ef473a")!, UIColor(hexString: "#cb2d3e")!].map { $0.cgColor }
        } else {
            cellgradient.colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#29a1e2")! , UIColor(hexString: "#485ac8")!].map { $0.cgColor }
        }
    }
}
func addthegradientLayer() {

    //the cells gradient colors
    cellgradient.frame = imageView.bounds
    cellgradient.cornerRadius = cellgradient.frame.height / 2
    cellgradient.colors = cellgradient.colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#29a1e2")! , UIColor(hexString: "#485ac8")!].map { $0.cgColor }
    cellgradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    cellgradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    imageView.layer.insertSublayer(cellgradient, at: 0)
}
```

And it works. Now I only got one problem left:
The imageview of the cell is hidden behind the gradient. 
How do I solve this?

Comment: Could you describe your view hierarchy a little more? It sounds like your collection view cell has a UIImageView in it, and you're adding a CAGradientLayer to the image view's layer. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly thats what I'm doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by [subclassing `UICollectionViewCell`](https://randexdev.com/2014/08/uicollectionviewcell/). Your custom cell class can have a property to reference its gradient layer.

In the cell's initializer, add the gradient layer to the image view like you do now. [Then, override the `isSelected` property's `didSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006234/what-is-the-purpose-of-willset-and-didset-in-swift) and modify the gradient layer for the selected or normal state.

Comment: As @yarn said, it appears you've used the same exact colors for both the selected and normal states.

Comment: Alright, that works now, my only problem now is that the image view is hidden.

Comment: @user8533118 Adding a sublayer to any UIView will cover other layers and subviews. Could you get around this by adding a UIView to the cell behind the image view and add the gradient layer to the sibling view?

Answer (score 0):

The hex string for colors are identical for both isSelected and !isSelecet in didSet{}.

Comment: @Moritz From user8533118's comment above, it sounds like I answered the original question of why there was no gradient change.

Answer (score 0):

If can insert your layer below or after current outlets

```
imageView.layer.insertSublayer(cellgradient, below: nameLabel.layer)
```