# Change button color in tableview cell row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a few buttons in a table view cell row

[image].

WhenI click the button, I want the button change the colour to yellow colour without affect another row of the button.  [image]. Example when I click the row 0 button then it will change to yellow colour, if I click on row 1 button will change to yellow as well but the row 0 and other row button will change back/stay at original colour.

Comment: You'll have to store the "selection" state of the button for each row/section in a kind of data model, and then in `tableView:cellForRowAt:` check the state and draw the button accordingly. To update the state, change the model and call `reloadCells...`.

Comment: You have to manage array for selected buttons

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can override `isHighlighted` or `isSelected` property.

An example (`Swift 3`) as following.

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var weak aButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet var weak aLabel: UILabel!

        override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            // custom selected behavior
            aButton.isSelected = isSelected
            aLabel.textColor = (isSelected ? UIColor.red : UIColor.blue)
           }
        }

        override var isHighlighted: Bool {
            didSet {
               // custom highlighted behavior
               aButton.isSelected = isHighlighted
               aLabel.textColor = (isHighlighted ? UIColor.red : UIColor.blue)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this will override `isHighlighted` or `isSelected` property of UITableViewCell instead of `UIButton`  right ?

Comment: `didSet` is property observation in `Swift`. You can refer [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006282/419348).