# How to make Boolean Value stay true after the first time it becomes true? (SWIFT)

Tags: swift

I need to make a box that stays red after my mouse enters the box. I have the code that works, but once my mouse leaves the box, it returns to white. Help?
I edited my code to show you guys more. Sorry, this is my first time using this site so I am kind of a noob.

```
override func update() {
        // ****** IMPORTANT - PLEASE NOTE ******
        // Variables declared here, inside the update function,
        // only remember values for one call (execution) to the update function.
        // When update is called again to redraw the view, a variable
        // declared inside the function will not remember its previous value.

        background(gray: 0.5)

        // *************************************************
        // Insert your drawing code here, below this comment
    rect(x: 200, y: 175, width: 75, height: 75)
    rect(x: 305, y: 175, width: 75, height: 75)
    rect(x: 410, y: 175, width: 75, height: 75)
    rect(x: 515, y: 175, width: 75, height: 75)

    var boxA = false

    if tin.mouseX >= 200.0 && tin.mouseX <= 275.0 && tin.mouseY >= 175.0 && tin.mouseY <= 250.0 {
              boxA = true
           }

    if boxA == true {
        fillColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        rect(x: 200, y: 175, width: 75, height: 75)
    }
```

Comment: Is this code part of a function? How is it called? Based on the snipped you posted, it is hard to answer your question. Could you provide more code.

Comment: When do you want to set it back to `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably `update` is being called as part of some drawing loop.  The comment at the start suggests what your problem is

```swift
// Variables declared here, inside the update function,
// only remember values for one call (execution) to the update function.
// When update is called again to redraw the view, a variable
// declared inside the function will not remember its previous value.
```

So you draw your rectangle:

```swift
rect(x: 200, y: 175, width: 75, height: 75)
```

which is presumably with a white background.  Then you have your test for being inside the rectangle:

```swift
var boxA = false
if tin.mouseX >= 200.0 ... {
  boxA = true
}
```

and finally you fill the rectangle with red if `boxA` is `true`.

But as soon as `update` finishes, the state of `boxA` is gone.  Next time through `update`, it's again set to `true` if and only if the mouse is inside the rectangle, so if you move it outside, it'll go back to `false`.

To fix it, you have to move `boxA` to some place where it won't get reset.  For example, if `update` is a method in some class, then you could make `boxA` an instance variable of the class.  E.g.,

```swift
class View {
  var boxA = false  // Here the state won't be lost after update finishes

  override func update() {
    ...
    // xxx var boxA = false xxx Don't put the declaration here
    if ... {
      boxA = true
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what function you're writing this snippet in. So, to make it simple, add a property observer to your boolean `boxA`:

```
var boxA = false {
    willSet {
        if newValue {  // Set red color only when the boxA is true
            fillColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            rect(x: 200, y: 175, width: 75, height: 75)
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more on the property observers here: [What is the purpose of willSet and didSet in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006234/what-is-the-purpose-of-willset-and-didset-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks @George_E

Comment: @George_E I added more of my code, does that change anything? Im a beginner coder so I am not understanding your reply. If i use the code you provided I would erase my if statement regarding tin.mouse, and the code wouldn't work

Comment: @gzaya Just to let you know - this isn’t my code. I only made an edit.